# How to shrink column when wider than the window?

Tags: google-sheets

I double clicked the column border so it expanded wider than the window. When I scroll to the left it jumps, so I can't see the previous column.

[image]

How do I shrink it down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can right-click the top of the column (<kbd>Command</kbd>+click on a Mac), choose "Resize column" and enter some reasonable value (the default is 100; the width is measured in pixels).